# Error 404 requestmapping and getmapping url doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, request-mapping, get-mapping

Hi I m beginner and I have a simple problem, my url doesn't work. localhost:8080 work but not with /api. The project is built properly.

[Localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzAhu.png)

I put @ComponentScan("com.tutojwt.test.repository") because without it doesn't work.

Here my code

Controller :

```
package com.tutojwt.test.api;

import com.tutojwt.test.model.User;
import com.tutojwt.test.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>>getUsers(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.getUsers());
    }
```

Testapplication :

```
package com.tutojwt.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.tutojwt.test.repository")
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Tcy.png)

MAJ : Some of you say that is ComponentScan the prob but there are error if I dont put com.tutojwt.test.repository or just com.tutojwt.test

[@ComponentScan("com.tutojwt.test") error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqH1h.png)

[Without ComponentScan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npk3f.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should call http://localhost:8080/api/users . @ComponentScan shouldn't be necessary and might actually cause problems (I don't think your controller class is scanned now, and some default hateoas endpoint is the one you're calling). @SpringBootApplication annotation has @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation by default and should scan all component annotated classes. If not, check your class structure again.

Comment: If I dont add Component scan there is an error.